# dao pattern into EJB3 JPA?

Tags: jpa, ejb, dao

Hi I have a project that uses EJB3 and JPA2, I have defined my EntityManager in the bean, but I want to add a DAO layer and the EntityManager is defined there to use the methods of the DAO from Bean to only get the result of the queries, leaving the business logic bean. Can you do this? How I can do? Thank you very much!

PD. I tried but i dont get it still.

Answer (score 0):

Why to use a separate layer like DAO? When using JPA, `EntityManager` plays role of DAO really well in most cases.

btw. you can take a look at this 7 years old article [JPA/EJB3 killed the DAO](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/jpa_ejb3_killed_the_dao).

Comment: Well, I used to program in ejb 2.0 and dao layer was separated from the bean, in the bean only have business logic and all my queries were in the dao, wanted to do something similar (per paradigm) but if your recommendation is to use direct EntityManager in removing the bean dao layer, so I'll use it, however I would like to separate the logic of data access.